# Проверка массива на чётность элементов

Tags: ассемблер, emu8086

Стоит задача проверить элементы массива на их чётность. Очевидно, сразу пришла идея  делить элемент массива на 2 и проверять остаток, но так я не могу сделать, ибо делимое всегда должно находится в регистре `ax`, а там у меня находится .data предыдущей задачи.

Не могли бы вы подсказать, в какую сторону двигаться?

Comment: Ну делайте and 1. Если чётное, то будет 0, иначе 1

Comment: спасибо большое, сработало, даже и не знал, что таким образом возможно это решить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name "mycode"

org  100h


.data
    alph db 'mals'
    rez db 200 dup(0)
    arr db 1,2,3,4,5,6,3,8,9
    len dw 9
    mov cx, len ; dlina massiva chisel dlya cikla
    mov ax, @data;reload data
    mov ds, ax
    mov al, 30h
cycle:
    ;proverka na chetnost:
    mov dl, 1
    mov bl, [arr+si]
    and dl, bl
    jnz next ;ne null perehod
    inc al
next:
    inc si
    loop cycle
;vivod
mov dl, al
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
```